# RxSwift: Observing UITextFields from TableViewCell inside a child view controller

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I have a tableView and a childController in a parent viewController, the tableView in the ParentViewController can have from 1 - 4 cells, each cell contains a UITextField.

The ChildController also have a TableView, that list results(autocomplete) based on what is inputted in any of the TextField in the ParentViewController tableView cell.

I want the childController to always listen to any of the UITextField and show the result on the tablView. This is what I have currently

```
private var query = Variable<String>("")
var queryDriver: Driver<String> {
    return query.asDriver()
}
```

TableView

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    guard let cell = tableView
        .dequeueReusableCell(
            withIdentifier: "StopCell", for: indexPath) as? StopCell else {
                fatalError("Cannot dequeue StopCell")
    }
    cell.delegate = self

    cell.locationTextField.rx.text.map {$0 ?? ""}
        .bind(to: query)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)

    cell.locationTextField.rx.controlEvent(.editingDidEnd)
        .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: ())
        .drive(onNext: { [unowned self] in
            cell.locationTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    return cell
}
```

Add child controller

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    let noteVC = NoteVc()
    addChildController(viewController: noteVC)
}
```

NoteVC

```
class NoteVc: UIViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    viewModel = SearchLocationViewModel(query: <#T##SharedSequence<DriverSharingStrategy, String>#>)
}
```

ViewModel

```
class SearchLocationViewModel {

let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
// MARK: - Properties

var querying: Driver<Bool> { return _querying.asDriver() }
var locations: Driver<[Location]> { return _locations.asDriver() }

// MARK: -

var hasLocations: Bool { return numberOfLocations > 0 }
var numberOfLocations: Int { return _locations.value.count }

// MARK: -

private let _querying = BehaviorRelay<Bool>(value: false)
private let _locations = BehaviorRelay<[Location]>(value: [])

// MARK: -

private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

// MARK: - Initializtion

init(query: Driver<String>) {
    Behave.shared.queryDriver
        .throttle(0.5)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .drive(onNext: { [weak self] (addressString) in
            self?.geocode(addressString: addressString)
        })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

Like it is implemented in the Uber app, users can add up to three destinations, the yellow rectangle box in the image below is my ChildViewController

[image]

Comment: you will need to bind the textfield's data to an array and then bind that array to the tableView of your child controller

Comment: @ShahzaibQureshi do you mind helping out with a code, I have tried but not getting it, I have also updated the question for it to be clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the simplest I could think of. I made viewModel a global constant but you might want to get more elaborate with it.:

```
class ViewModel {
    let inputs: [AnyObserver<String>]
    let outputs: [Observable<String>]

    init(count: Int) {
        let subjects = (0..<count).map { _ in BehaviorSubject<String>(value: "") }
        inputs = subjects.map { $0.asObserver() }
        outputs = subjects.map { $0.asObservable() }
    }
}

class ParentViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let bag = self.bag
        Observable.just(viewModel.inputs)
            .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "Cell", cellType: UITableViewCell.self)) { _, element, cell in
                let textField = cell.viewWithTag(99) as! UITextField
                textField.rx.text.orEmpty
                    .bind(to: element)
                    .disposed(by: bag)
            }
            .disposed(by: bag)
    }

    let bag = DisposeBag()
}

class ChildViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let bag = self.bag
        Observable.just(viewModel.outputs)
            .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "Cell", cellType: UITableViewCell.self)) { _, element, cell in
                element
                    .bind(to: cell.textLabel!.rx.text)
                    .disposed(by: bag)
            }
            .disposed(by: bag)
    }

    let bag = DisposeBag()
}
```

Comment: Hello Daniel, sorry for the late response, actually I have been trying to replicate the solution above, but I might need you to help edit the answer, I have updated the question with an image attached.